# Get the same value from all indices of an array in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I try to get a value that is repeated in all the indices of an array but I can't get it.

What I need to get is the RuleName value of each index in the array, so that the result will be:

```
P005DYQ, P005DYD
```

My array is the following:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> $array

instance of SMS_CollectionRuleDirect
{
    ResourceClassName = "R_System";
    ResourceID = 79023;
    RuleName = "P005DYQ";
};


instance of SMS_CollectionRuleDirect
{
    ResourceClassName = "R_System";
    ResourceID = 9024;
    RuleName = "P005DYD";
};
```

How can I get the RuleName values so that the result is P005DYQ and P005DYD?

Comment: `$array.RuleName` or  `$array | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RuleName`.

Comment: Is this what the console actually shows when you issue `$array` at the prompt? How did you populate this array in the first place?

Comment: $array is the result of the Get-CMCollection cmdlet;

$processed = Get-CMCollection -server $server -credential $credential -plataform $platform

$ array = $processed.output.CollectionRules